# Hamiltonian graph

Tags: graph-theory, hamiltonicity

Let $G$ be a graph with $n+k$ vertices such that $n$ vertices have degree at least $\frac{n+k}{2}$ and the remaining $k$ vertices have degree at least $k+1$. Show that G is Hamiltonian.

Using Diracs Theorem I need to show that the minimum degree of G is bigger that $\frac{n+k}{2}$.
which implies I have to show that $k+2 \geq n$.

It is clear that each of the $k$ vertices have at least 2 neighbours of among the $n$ vertices.

How can I use this to prove that G is Hamiltonian?

Comment: You may also want to try use Ore's Theorem, which gives a slightly easier to meet condition: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ore%27s_theorem

Comment: @BrandonduPreez thanks for the hint! using this it is clear that if the vertices are among the first $n$ then $d(v) + d(w) \geq n + k$ but if they are among the $k$ or one from each set, I get again $k+2 \geq n$. and them I am stuck again.

Comment: The [Bondy-Chvátal theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_path#Bondy%E2%80%93Chv%C3%A1tal_theorem) will do the job.